# If the condition of <if> statement is False, doesn't we have to just skip it?

Tags: python

```
mysum=0
for i in range(5,11,2):
      mysum += i
      if mysum ==5:
         break
         mysum += 1
print(mysum)  // always prints: 5
```

I don't understand why the result is just '5'.
I think if the condition of **if** statement is False, then it would skip the code block.  Let me explain how I understand this code.

1. (When mysum is 5): The `if` statement is going to be `true`. So, it goes into the code block, and there is `break` statement, so it exits the code block. In that case, the result of `print(mysum)` is `5`.
2. (When mysum is 7 or 9): The `if` statement is going to be `false`. So, it skips past the code block, and prints of the result of `print(mysum)`, which is `7` or `9`.

But there is only `5` in result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: but but the loop stops at the first iteration when `mysum == 5`

Comment: Your `break` statement will exit the for loop completely.

Comment: He appended `=5` to show the output :)

Comment: If you want to continue to the next iteration of the loop, use `continue` instead of `break`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If instead of breaking from the loop, you'd like to merely go to the next iteration, you should use the `continue` keyword.

```
for x in xs:
    if x == target:
        break
    f(x)
```

will stop execution once anything equals `target` and run `f(x)` for every `x` before it whereas

```
for x in xs:
    if x == target:
        continue
    f(x)
```

Will run `f(x)` for every `x` in `xs` not equal to `target`.

Answer (score 0):

#1 is correct, and #2 would almost be true if the loop executed for i = 7 and i = 9, but after the code does the `print` for the first time, it's done.

This would give the output you describe:

```
for i in range(5, 11, 2):
      mysum = i
      print(mysum)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mysum=0
for i in range(5,11,2):
    mysum += i
    if mysum ==5:
        mysum += 1
        break
print(mysum)=5
```

`break` is used to stop a loop in progress prematurely. 
When it's called it stops iterating the loop, meaning that `mysum` will never return the `True` Boolean and ultimately will never `mysum+=1`

Comment: Edited for you Moxie

Comment: `+=` is the logical operator to add and change an object. Not sure the exact definition but a quick Google search will set you on the correct path to enliggtenment

Comment: And why is that exactly?